# iPad GUI only updates after touch

Tags: objective-c, ios, multithreading, ipad

Im building a multithreaded app for the iPad. I have this class that extracts frames from movie clip and I have a UIScrollView to show the things I extracted. The frame extractor is running in a different thread and I want to start build the scroll view only after I extracted certain amount of frames. Therefore, I created this BOOL property called buffering which im updating through the thread. My view controller observe this property and only after this property equals to NO im starting to build the ScrollView.

The problem is that I dont see any change in the GUI after the building method is called. I can only see the scroll view after I touch the screen

Heres what im doing:

To create the thread:

`[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(startReading) toTarget:self withObject:nil];`

The code running in the thread:

```
-(void) startReadingWithTimeRange:(STimeRange *) timeRange;
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init]; // Top-level pool
    //setting the time range for reading the file
    [assetReader setTimeRange:timeRange.timeRange];

    //start reading
    [assetReader startReading];

    //declearing about the buffer
    CMSampleBufferRef buffer;
    int z = 0;
    while ( [assetReader status]==AVAssetReaderStatusReading)
    {
        z++;
        //reading buffer
        buffer = [assetReaderTrackOutput copyNextSampleBuffer];

        if (buffer == NULL) break;
        //converting the buffer to UIImage
        UIImage *frameImage = imageFromSampleBuffer(buffer);
        CMTime time = CMSampleBufferGetOutputPresentationTimeStamp(buffer);
        NSLog(@"###duration %lld",time.value/time.timescale);


        SFrame *frame = [[SFrame alloc] initWithImage:frameImage andTime:time];
        //add it to the frame array
        [framesArray addObject:frame];

        [frame release];
        //check if buffer is not null and needed release


        //release the buffer
        CFRelease(buffer);


        if ([framesArray count] > 100 && self.buffering) {
            [self willChangeValueForKey:@"buffering"];
            self.buffering = NO;
            [self didChangeValueForKey:@"buffering"];

        }


    }
    [pool release];

}
```

Im really clueless I'd really appreciate any help

Comment: Your selector doesn't match the method name...

Comment: `startReading` only calles `startReadingWithTimeRange:` with the right  range

Comment: The interesting part is probably the code where you actually "build the scroll view". My guess would be that you need a `setNeedsDisplay` call somewhere.

Comment: @Or.Ron, Did you find the solution for this problem? I've the same problem now.

Answer (score 1):

First off do not call willChangeValueForKey and didChangeValueForKey as you are only making the KVO notification fire twice, it is already fired by self.buffering = NO;

Secondly property/ivar changes outside the main thread should be done inside a @synchronized block e.g.:

```
@synchronized (self) {
     self.buffering = NO;
}
```

You could alternately use performSelectorOnMainThread to call a buffering method e.g.:

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(buffering:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] waitUntilDone:NO];
```

If doing this does not solve your issue then you might have another problem in your code e.g. needing to call setNeedsDisplay on some view or the kind.

You did not say what happens with the KVO notification, do you not get it that is why you explicitly tried to send it ?

Comment: He should use `performSelectorOnMainThread:...` probably; I'll wager he doesn't hop onto the main thread in his KVO notification and therefore ends up (illegally) doing UIKit tasks on a background thread.

Comment: just for the record it is easy to check your tread with [NSThread isMainThread] and see